# Celery pool parameter ignored in setup_defaults?

Tags: python, celery, pool

I have a script that run the Celery Worker like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        worker = celery.Worker()
        worker.setup_defaults(
            loglevel=logging.INFO,
            pool='eventlet',
            concurrency=500
        )
        worker.start()
```

This launches Celery, as the output is :

```
 -------------- celery@some.server.com v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.0-19-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2022-12-14 15:23:55
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7fdda296baf0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/6
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/6
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 500 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . task1
  . task2
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
```

But, somehow, the processes are running as Fork:

```
[2022-12-14 15:08:00,623: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] - Some print command
[2022-12-14 15:08:00,623: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] - Some print command
```

So I thought maybe the concurrency was off, so I tried with gevent. It's the same.

So I tried something else, I replaced "eventlet" with a random text ; "helloworld", and here's the output:

```
 -------------- celery@some.server.com v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.0-19-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2022-12-14 15:23:55
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7fdda296baf0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/6
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/6
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 500 (helloworld)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . task1
  . task2
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
```

I mean, what?

Celery should fail if the pool isn't correct, but here, nothing happens.

What is even weirder is that it was working fine previously and stopped yesterday without any changes on my end at all.

Was there some recent updates that affect how the pool is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason is because somehow, calling `setup_defaults` is ignored.

The right way to do is :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        worker = celery.Worker(
            loglevel=logging.INFO,
            pool='eventlet',
            concurrency=500
        )
        worker.start()
```

This will seriously take into consideration the pool (and setting it to dumb values will fail)